# Hibernate column mapping and collection lazy loading

Tags: oracle, hibernate

There is a Hibernate 3.5.2 application, which I would like to be able to connect to either Postgres or Oracle. The two schemata are similar, but in Oracle, table and column names are chopped to 30 chars max. Class names and class property names follow the Postgres table and column names. In "HibernateUtil.java", the configuration reads the .xml files, then the connection url is examined and if it is Oracle, a table and column name mapping happens:

```
Iterator<Table> tableIterator = configuration.getTableMappings(); 
while (tableIterator.hasNext()) { 
    Table table = tableIterator.next(); 
    if (table.getName().length() > 30) {
        table.setName(table.getName().substring(0, 30));
    }

    Iterator<Column> columnIterator = table.getColumnIterator(); 
    while (columnIterator.hasNext()) { 
        Column column = columnIterator.next(); 
        if (column.getName().length() > 30) { 
            column.setName(column.getName().substring(0, 30)); 
        } 
    } 
}
configuration.buildMappings();
```

Then the session is opened.

There exist among others a “table_a” and a “table_b”, “table_b” has a column that references the primary key of “table_a”.

“TableA.hbm.xml” looks like:

```
...
<set name="tableB" table="table_b" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
    <key>
        <column name="refid_with_long_name_more_than_30_chars" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="blabla" />
</set>
...
```

“TableB.hbm.xml” looks like:

```
...
<many-to-one name="tableA" class="blabla" fetch="select">
    <column name="refid_with_long_name_more_than_30_chars" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
...
```

Everything runs OK until a lazy load happens (one “TableA” instance tries to load the “Set of TableB”). In the sql query produced, the foreign key is used with its original 30+ chars length name. Looks like:

select refid_with_long_name_more_than_30_chars ...

This causes an “Identifier too long” exception.

If I edit “TableA.hbm.xml” and chop the column name “refid_with_long_name_more_than_30_chars” to 30 chars, it will work (for Oracle). But I prefer not to do this, I prefer to do it dynamically in “HibernateUtil.java”.

I have not found where to configure this. On the other hand, I have the impression that, as soon as I have done properly the column mapping, there should be nothing more to configure (or not?)

The question is: Apart from the column mapping, there exists something more I have to do, in order to instruct the lazy load to use the new chopped column name?

Comment: It's unclear why you are trying to keep your `refid_with_long_name_more_than_30_chars` column name... Why don't you redefine this name to a shorter value, in order to solve everything instantly?

Comment: Hi Vincent, renaming the column will definitely solve it. I am just trying not to reengineer the Postgres db and I am wandering if I am missing something obvious in the mapping.